# pull json data with ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to pull in some json data using ajax. I am able to successfully pull data from the first 2 items but its the data under "placemark" that I really need. I need to be able to display this in a list much like an rssfeed. I'm not sure how to drill down deeper into the json to pull the data I need. any help greatly appreciated.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: rssAPI,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            $.each(item, function(key, value) {
                $('.listing').append(key + ': ' + value + '</br>');
            });
        });
    }
});
```

here's what my json looks like
[image]

and this is my output
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either output, if the property value is a string, or iterate further (i.e. another loop) if it's an array, as is the case with the `Placemark` properties.

So:

```
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        $.each(item, function(key, value) {
            if (typeof value != 'object')
                $('.listing').append(key + ': ' + value + '</br>');
            else
                $.each(value, function(key, value) {
                    //these are your items under Placemark
                });
        });
    });
```

Comment: How would I go about appending the Placemark items?

Comment: Erm, maybe you should look at my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Here placemark contains array of json objects. So you need to access it as below :

```
for(i=0; i<Document.Placemark; i++){

    console.log(Document.Placemark[i].name);
    console.log(Document.Placemark[i].description);

}
```